# Button action done when touched outside of keyboard - Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am using the following code to enter a value in `UITextfield` 'item', then on clicking button `addButton` the value in `textfield` will be appended to an array and then clear the `textfield`. I have also added a code that will hide the keyboard when touched outside.

The problem is, after typing a word in `textfield`, then touching outside, the action in the button in done, even before the button is pressed

```
@IBOutlet weak var item: UITextField!

@IBAction func addButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    toDoList.append(item.text!)
    item.text = ""
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    self.view.endEditing(true)

}
```

Comment: "the action in the button in done, even before the button is pressed" Can you clear more about this?.

Comment: These two lines "toDoList.append(item.text!)
    item.text = "" " are executed when i touch outside of keyboard

Comment: Check your Interface Builder, sure about `addButton`.

Comment: i am new to swift. Should i have to do something on dragging textfield to code? The event default is "Editing did end"

Comment: `addButton` is connecting with what?

Comment: what does that mean? I didn't get it

Comment: Is there a button for `addButton`?  If no, what calls `addButton`?

Comment: Yes i have created a button. Then dragged it to code, put action instead of outlet. Then put a name to that button 'addbutton'

Comment: I think `addButton` is called by something like "Editing did end". Did you add break point and see what is calling it?

Comment: I got it fixed! Changed event as "touch up inside"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the problem, but this will help you because you are new to swift,

1. First Delete the

   ```
    @IBOutlet weak var item: UITextField!  

   &   

    @IBAction func addButton(sender: AnyObject) {

     toDoList.append(item.text!)
     item.text = ""
    }
   ```

02.Then go to the story board click the view controller  and click the last button with the sign of arrow to right. Check the outlets. Delete item and add button on that list.

3. Then again add text field and add button to the view controller. 
   click the text field + ctrl ad connect the line with the view controllers code, do the same for the addButton ,use touch up inside not touching outside
4. add these functions to code and run the project.

   ```
   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
   self.view.endEditing(true)
   ```

   }

   ```
   func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

   textField.resignFirstResponder()
   return true
   ```

   }

hope these steps will help you. If not leave a comment

Answer (score 0):

While dragging button into code, set event as "touch up inside"